# Why is my fescue wilting?

Tags: lawn, grass, fescue

I have replanted my entire front yard lawn with fescue grass. I scraped off all the existing grass and all weeds. Then place a pervious mat to reduce new weeds from coming through. On top of this mat I introduced 2 inches of top soil and replanted using rolls of seed using Grotrax rolls.  I also introduced some Purely Organic Dry Lawn Food and watered at least 3 times per day when it was not raining. The grass came up lush and green. However, 3 months in I am getting brown patches where all the grass seemed to have died.

Can someone help with explaining what might have gone wrong?  Could it be brown spot disease?  And how could I remedy the situation?

Comment: What sort of mat.  Please post photos of the mat and the patches

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert but growing a lawn two inches over a membrane definitely doesn't sound a good idea. The membrane will prevent the grass roots growing down into the underlying soil. That means the lawn will be susceptible to drying out during dry spells. Turf grass is amazingly resilient stuff, but you do need to let the roots go down as far as they want to. I notice the GrowTrax [website](https://grotrax.com/pages/howto) also doesn't mention using a membrane. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.